# On the Mac App Store, is the NEVPNManager allowed to be used?

Tags: cocoa, nevpnmanager

On the Mac App Store, is the NEVPNManager allowed to be used to build a VPN client personalised for a provider and also set the VPN settings for the user ?
I think I know the answer on iOs, and it is yes, I have seen it in many apps, but what about Mac ? anybody with specific experience ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible since El Capitan